# RegionMember not working with negative vertices

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, regions, geometry

I am using `RegionMember[]` to determine wether a point is within a shape.

```
shape1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]
RegionMember[shape1, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]
```

Returns `True`, but this doesn't

```
shape2 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, -1}]
RegionMember[shape2, {0.5, 0.5, -0.5}]
```

Any ideas on why this is the case, or how to fix. I would like a `True` returned if the point is within the `Cuboid`.

Comment: In versions 10.0.1 and 10.4.1 `RegionMember[shape2, {0.5, 0.5, -0.5}]` generates a message `RegionMember::regp: "A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionMember[Cuboid[{0,0,0},{1,1,-1}],{0.5,0.5,-0.5}]."`, but in versions 11.1.1 and 11.2.0 it doesn't.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ah. Now I get it. I also got the message (v 11.0.1) but wondered how this can be overlooked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `shape2 = Cuboid[{0, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 0}]` or `Cuboid @@ Transpose[Sort /@ Transpose[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, -1}}]]`. Mathematica expects that the entries of the first argument list are all less or equal the respective entries of the second argument list.

Comment: Isn't this assumption unexpected?

Comment: @Kuba `?Cuboid` says `Cuboid[Subscript[p, min],Subscript[p, max]] represents an axis-aligned filled cuboid with lower corner Subscript[p, min] and upper corner Subscript[p, max].` I see "min", "max" and "lower corner" and "upper corner", so no, I don't think that this should be considered unexpected. Moreover, the documentation page is also quite detailed about it. Btw: `Graphics3D` accepts `Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, -1}]`, but it gets the rendering wrong.

Comment: I know it is for people but for arbitrary `ViewVertical`, terms lower/upper make not so much sense. p.s. I can't reproduce the problem with rendering, what exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: @Kuba Since the normals point inwards, the shading is not computed correctly. But maybe this is also version specific?

Comment: Maybe, for:`Graphics3D[{
  Red, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, -1}],
  Translate[Cuboid[{0, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 0}], {1, 1, 1}],
  Translate[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, -1}], 2 {1, 1, 1}]
  }]` I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiSyA.png where I guess the middle one should differ.

Comment: But anyway, my remark about `ViewVertical` holds so either `Cuboid` should return a message or documentation should be more precise.

Comment: @Kuba Interesting, I obtain https://i.stack.imgur.com/beSV9.png with version 11.0.1.

Comment: @Kuba Getting an error message from `Cuboid` might be difficult as it was orginally meant merely as a wrapper for `Graphics3D`. But I am with you that at least `RegionMember` should tell us that something is going wrong. Actually in v 11.0.1 it does...